# Ambiguousness in Android Java source

Tags: java, android

```
EditText ed1 = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.editText1 );

int a = Integer.parseInt( ed1.getText().toString() );
```

Does the above code get the input as numeric from the user and show it as a string?

My requirement is to get the input as integer and return as Strings. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String ed1Str = ed1.getText().toString().trim();
int a = Integer.parseInt(ed1Str);
```

Will make it available as an integer (`int a`) and as a string (`String ed1Str`)

Comment: you should add trim() while fetching string from EditText(), it will prevent you from empty string, if any.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the above code referencing that get the input as numeric from the user and show it as string?

The other way round - it's going through these steps:

- Find the EditBox
- Get the *text* from the edit box
- Parse the text as a number

> My requirement is to get the input as integer and return as Strings

Get the input from where? If you're getting the input from a *user* then it's probably already in a string form. If you're trying to convert an integer from somewhere else in the code, then you *could* use

```
String text = Integer.toString(number);
```

... or you could use a `NumberFormat` object, which would take different cultural information into account, allowing for grouping of digits etc.

Answer (score 2):

The EditText.getText() returns Editable object and  you have to convert it to string. You cannot get the number directly from edit text. You can access the text returned from EditText, convert it to String and then covert it into number as you have implemented.

Answer (score 2):

do little modification in above code **ed1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);**
that will make your edittext **only to accept integer values**..